# How do I make a CGImage into a 1 bit per pixel PNG file on OS X using CoreGraphics?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, core-graphics

I've been struggling all week with this one. My first few attempts landed me with RGBA images from a monochrome image. I've gotten down to 8bit gray scale. But I need more compression. Indexed is the way to go but I have found no sample code or documentation (and I've looked) to do it. I've already asked on the Apple Developer Forums and came up blank so far.

I'm using Swift 1.2 in Xcode 6.3.1 targeting OS X 10.10. Here is a relevant section of code.

```
func createBitmapContext (size: CGRect) -> CGContext! {
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,
        Int(size.width),
        Int(size.height),
        8,
        0,
        CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(),
        CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.None.rawValue))
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationNone)
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, false)

    return context
}

func createCGImage(ci: CIImage) -> CGImage? {
    let contextOptions = [kCIContextOutputColorSpace: NSNull(),
        kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull(),
        kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: true]
    let cgContext = createBitmapContext(ci.extent())
    let context = CIContext(CGContext: cgContext, options: contextOptions as [NSObject : AnyObject])

    CGContextDrawImage(cgContext, ci.extent(), context.createCGImage(ci, fromRect: ci.extent()))

    return CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cgContext)
}

func saveImage(path: String, image: NSData) {
    image.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
}

func getImageFileData(image: CGImage) -> NSData? {
    var pngDataRef = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0)
    let pngDest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(pngDataRef, kUTTypePNG, 1, nil)
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(pngDest, image, nil)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(pngDest)

    return pngDataRef
}
```

The code takes a CIImage that is already B&W. It gets rendered into a supported context to create a gray scale CGImage. I have not found a way to create an Indexed context. The image destination is an NSData object because I want to do some work with it before I spit it out to a file. The NSData object contains the file data as it will appear on disk.

What I want is an indexed image that is one bit per pixel. I know that PNG supports that format and that OS X will read it. I just haven't figured out how to create it.

Help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1 bit per pixel it is not grayscale it is BW

Comment: Image IO is the framework you're after

Comment: I've been all through Image IO. I'll keep looking. I should have been clearer that I want B&W / Monochromatic, not grayscale. I was getting an error that 1 instead of 8 was not a supported context. How do I configure CGBitmapContextCreate for Monochrome? It's not listed in the supported pixel formats. If the method is to create a destination that will do 1 bit indexed, how do I do that? Thanks.